# Enemy Animator unity3d(2d) returning animator not initialized

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

This is my enemy I'm cloning (instantiating). I have an error and I have set up everything correct I think.

#### Error:

> Animator has not been initialized.
>   UnityEngine.Animator:SetFloat(String, Single) enemyscript:playerhit()
>   (at Assets/enemies/enemyscript.js:14)

How do I initialise the animator in every clone.

```
#pragma strict
var enemysmall : GameObject;
var speed : float = 1.0;
var anim : Animator;

function Start() {
  this.transform.position.x = 8.325;
  this.transform.position.y = -1.2;
  anim = GetComponent(Animator);
  anim.SetFloat("enemy1sta",0);
}

function playerhit() {
  anim.SetFloat("enemy1sta",1);
}

function Update() {
  this.transform.Translate(Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0));
  this.rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2(-5, 0);
}
```

This is my on my player to spawn them from a prefab

```
 var enemy1 : Transform;

 function Start () { 
 ///enemy1
   while (true) {
     yield WaitForSeconds (Random.Range(3, 5));
     var enemy1Clone : Transform = Instantiate(enemy1, transform.position, transform.rotation);
     enemy1Clone.GetComponent("enemyscript");
     enemy1Clone.GetComponent(Animator);
   }
}
```

And I'm using a simple

```
function OnCollisionEnter2D(coll: Collision2D) {
  if (coll.gameObject.CompareTag("enemy") && jumped==true){
    other.playerhit();   < ----- i have it so this calls the enemy function.
    //Destroy(coll.gameObject);
    jumpup(); 
    jumped = true;
    combo += 1;
    GUIcombo.text = "COMBO: " + combo;
  }
}
```

can someone help me with this bug its really getting me down on my first game dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to store Components in the same variable. This is wrong:

```
var enemy1Clone : Transform = Instantiate(enemy1, transform.position, transform.rotation);
enemy1Clone.GetComponent("enemyscript");
enemy1Clone.GetComponent(Animator);
```

`enemy1Clone` is of type `Transform`, don't try putting `enemyscript` or `Animator` Components inside of it.

You don't need those 2 `GetComponent` so just discard them.

---

I have completely changed the logic for your game. It works now.

**Player.js**

```
function Awake()
{
    GUIcombo.text = "COMBO: ";
    GUIlives.text = "LIVES: 3";
}


function Start () 
{ 
    anim = GetComponent(Animator);
}


function Update () 
{
    if(lives <= 0)
        Destroy(Player);

    Player.transform.position.x = -4.325;

    if(!jumped)
        anim.SetFloat("hf",0.0);

    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && !jumped)
    {
        jumpup();
        jumped = true;

        anim.SetFloat("hf",1);
    }
}


function OnCollisionEnter2D(coll: Collision2D) 
{
    var g : GameObject = coll.gameObject;

    if(g.CompareTag("ground"))
    {
        anim.SetFloat("hf",0.0);
        jumped=false;
        combo = 0;
        GUIcombo.text = "COMBO: " + combo;
    }

    else if(g.CompareTag("enemy") && jumped)
    {   
        // Notify the Enemy to die.
        g.SendMessage("die");

        jumpup(); 
        jumped=true;
        combo += 1;
        GUIcombo.text = "COMBO: " + combo;
    }

    else if(g.CompareTag("enemy") && !jumped)
    {
        lives -=1;
        GUIlives.text = "LIVES: " + lives;
    }
}


function slam()
{
    Player.rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0,-3000), ForceMode2D.Force);
}

function glide()
{
    Player.rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2(0,600), ForceMode2D.Force);
}

function jumpup()
{
    Player.transform.Translate(Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0));
    Player.rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2(0,10);

    if(jumplevel2)
        Player.rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2(0,13);

    if(jumplevel3)
        Player.rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2(0,16);
}
```

**Enemy.js**

```
#pragma strict

var enemy : GameObject;
var speed : float = 1.0;
var anim : Animator;
var isDead : boolean = false;

function Start()
{
   anim = GetComponent(Animator);
   anim.SetFloat("EnemyDie", 0);
   enemy.transform.position.x = 8.325;
   enemy.transform.position.y = -1.2;
}

function Update()
{
    if(!isDead)
    {
        enemy.transform.Translate(Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0));
        enemy.rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2(-5, 0);
    }
}

// Call here when enemy should die. 
function die()
{
    if(!isDead)
    {
        isDead = true;
        anim.SetFloat("EnemyDie", 1);

        yield WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: what should i do then please help would be really appreciated ?

Comment: i deleted those 2 statements and left it function Start () { 
///enemy1
while (true) {
         yield WaitForSeconds (Random.Range(3, 5));
var enemy1Clone : Transform = Instantiate(enemy1, transform.position, transform.rotation);
}

Comment: @kylehadley Any reason why you keep using this `SetFloat()` to play animations?

Comment: there mechanim animations and they have 2 animations states walking or dead, in my animator (i just started unity) and the only way i know how to change mech animation is by making a parameter with a float

Comment: could you help me fix this please to get a better understanding of unity

Comment: function playerhit(){
    anim.SetFloat("enemy1sta",1);   < points me to this line
    }

Comment: Wrap it around an `if(anim != null)` The thing is you are not finding the Animator Component attached to your Enemy GameObject.

Comment: my prefab got a bubble in the animator saying not initialised but i have a controller and its in place ect... my main character is done the same way so it shouldnt be the setup its the code somehow could you try make me a fixed pastebin ?

Comment: if(anim != null) how do i use this ? please

Comment: @kylehadley the same I did it in my example. Any time you call `anim.SetFloat` put an `if` before that. You will notice that the problem is that there is no `Animator` attached to your GameObject.

Comment: yeah i added you null statment and the animator seems to be there because when i change the value of my float via the animation window it works and only the clones on screen change.... maybe my other script call need tweaking to change the value of the float when my player hits an enemy

Comment: @kylehadley Does your Enemy look like the GameObject in the video I posted above?

Comment: want to take controll of my computer ?

Comment: http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx btw you never posted a video can you fix this for me please

Comment: I have to go now. I'll help you tomorrow if you are still having problems.

Comment: what is the var g : GameObject if you dont mind me asking bro

Comment: I use that as a temporary variable to avoid writing `coll.gameObject` a bunch of times.

Comment: will it effect my other collisions? if i make another enemy

Comment: also i have gotten so far

Comment: going to draw up my characters tomorrow

Comment: things i have implemented @FunctionR * save var locally * level up system * audio * and disable enemy collider on collision

Comment: i also have a bar for the exp

Comment: how would i instantiate a gui text ?

Comment: It should not affect the collisions. I think you can instantiate it using plain `Instantiate`. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Answer (score 0):

if the **Animator** is not initialized, you have to re-order the components, put the **Animator** component right below the **Transform** component and you should be fine.